# Recommendationf for Quiz Plugin that saves results

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

I'm building a learning site, and need a quiz plugin that will help track student progress through the lessons; thus I want a log of each member that took the quiz, along with date time and score.  Does anything like that exist?

Answer (score 1):

Check **[WP Survey And Quiz Tool](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-survey-and-quiz-tool/)** and **[mTouch Quiz](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mtouch-quiz/)** — both are very well maintained, and seem to do what you want (they show the score at the end of the quiz).

Just in case you didn't know, you can search for plugins based on keywords (in your case "quiz")—head to the [WordPress Plugins Repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/). :)

Comment: Thanks, I did search, but read features carefullly on mTouch, and never saw anything about saving the data.  You know, sometimes a recommendation is better than reading through 20 cheap plugins.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind splitting<sup>1</sup> the administration, you could use a [Google Docs Form](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/forms/).

> **Get answers to your questions**
>   Create simple or in-depth online surveys. Share them from a link,
>   embed them on your website, or even right inside an email.
>
> **Sit back and watch the results come in**
>   All responses to your questions are neatly organized in a Google
>   spreadsheet, so sorting and analyzing data is a snap.

Then, it's a matter of using the embed code to display the Quiz in a page/post.
:
Haven't used none yet, but there are some few [interesting plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=google%20docs) to integrate gDocs in WordPress.

---

<sup>**1 - Without splitting**</sup>
The following method is just a random idea and may have shortcomings that I'm not aware, but behaved quite well in my tests.

The code will create an administrative menu item that embeds the editing of an specific gDocument in WordPress dashboard. What's displayed in the dashboard are the results of the quiz in a Spreadsheet. The Form editing is done through the menu `Form (2)` (opens a pop-up).

[image: google docs embedded in wordpress]

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Embed gDocs in Admin
 */

add_action('admin_menu', 'add_gdocs_menu_wpse_58332');

function add_gdocs_menu_wpse_58332() 
{
    // Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page
    add_menu_page( 
        'gDocs', 
        '<span style="color:#000;">Google Docs</span>', 
        'edit_pages', 
        'gdocs', 
        'gdocs_iframe_wpse_58332', 
        'http://i.imgur.com/Vk42k.png', 
        6 // position, just after Posts
    );
}

/* Get the link in SHARING > LINK TO SHARE (allows editing) */
function gdocs_iframe_wpse_58332() 
{
    ?>
    <div class="wraper">
        <iframe 
            src ="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=THE_DOCUMENT_KEY_HERE&usp=sharing" 
            width="100%" height="700" />
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

For the *score* issue, [this tutorial](http://planetoftheweb.com/components/promos.php?id=534) has the Spreadsheet formula solution.

Comment: ps.: I guess the user control in gDocs would have to be done manually in the form: `User name: ________ [*Required]`