# How to add a button to check the emails of my domain?

Tags: plugins, email

I am looking for a button in the main menu that I can click it and then can send me to ask my email and password and after I put it I can see my emails from my domain.

Why?

Because I have workers and I give some emails from my domain and they need to check it, and I don't want to use outlook or mail softwares. I will like to use online webmail. And will be cool that I can add a botton like "Check Mail" all this in my website so they can get inside the company website and then click check mail and they will ask for the mail login from my domain emails.

How can I do this?

Comment: Sure all this for my wordpress website

Comment: It sounds like you just need to make a link to your Web Mail server?

Comment: I cannot find it, but I'm quite sure a similar question ended up with *"WordPress is not meant to be an email reader"*. Depending on the web mail service, you could [try to embed it](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58374/12615) as an iframe in the admin area.. . . **And also**, took the liberty to remove the plugin recommendation from title and content (it is off-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment in the Question, I tested the solution of adding a menu item that opens an `iframe` in its screen.

As expected, Gmail doesn't allow to be displayed in an `iframe`. But a regular Horde Webmail does work.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'embed_webmail_wpse_91871' );

function embed_webmail_wpse_91871() 
{
    // Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page
    // Check it, specially regarding the last parameter ($position), i.e.: 6
    add_menu_page( 
        'webmail', 
        'Webmail', 
        'edit_pages', 
        'webmail', 
        'webmail_iframe_wpse_91871', 
        'http://i.imgur.com/Vk42k.png', 
        4 // position, just after Dashboard
    );
}

function webmail_iframe_wpse_91871() 
{
    ?>
    <div class="wraper">
        <iframe 
            src ="http://example.com/webmail" 
            width="100%" height="700" />
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Results in:

[image: wordpress webmail]

Particularly, I've never seen a plugin for doing webmail inside WordPress.
In my opinion:

- seems excessively complex for something that simply needs a new browser tab to work.
- sounds like embedding Outlook into Word.